# Web site loading speed is slow

Tags: performance, web, pagespeed

My website http://theminimall.com  is taking more loading time than before

initially i had ny server in US at that time my website speed is around 5 sec.
but now i had transferred my server to Singapore and loading speed is got increased is about 10 sec.

the more waiting time is going in getting result from Store Procedure(sql server database)
but when i execute Store Procedure in Sql Server it is returning result very fast

so i assume that the time taken is not due to the query execution delay but the data transfer time from the sql server to the web server how can i eliminate or reduce the time taken any help or advice will be appreciated

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at your site on websitetest.com. You can see the test here: http://www.websitetest.com/ui/tests/50c62366bdf73026db00029e.

I can see what you mean about the performance. In Singapore, it's definitely fastest, but even there its pretty slow. Elsewhere around the world it's even worse. There are a few things I would look at.

First pick any sample, such as http://www.websitetest.com/ui/tests/50c62366bdf73026db00029e/samples/50c6253a0fdd7f07060012b6. Now you can get some of this info in the Chrome DevTools, or FireBug, but the advantage here is seeing the measurements from different locations around the world.

Scroll down to the waterfall. All the way on the right side of the Timeline column heading is a drop down. Choose to sort descending. Here we can see the real bottlenecks. The first thing in the view is GetSellerRoller.json. It looks like hardly any time is spent downloading the file. Almost all the time is spent waiting for the server to generate the file. I see the site is using IIS and ASP.net. I would definitely look at taking advantage of some server-side caching to speed this up.

The same is true for the main html, though a bit more time is spent downloading that file. Looks like its taking so long to download because it's a huge file (for html). I would take the inline CSS and JS out of there.

Go back to the natural order for the timeline, then you can try changing the type of file to show. Looks like you have 10 CSS files you are loading, so take a look at concatenating those CSS files and compressing them.

I see your site has to make 220+ connection to download everything. Thats a huge number. Try to eliminate some of those.

Next down the list I see some big jpg files. Most of these again are waiting on the server, but some are taking a while to download. I looked at one of a laptop and was able to convert to a highly compressed png and save 30% on the size and get a file that looked the same. Then I noticed that there are well over 100 images, many of which are really small. One of the big drags on your site is that there are so many connections that need to be managed by the browser. Take a look at implementing CSS Sprites for those small images. You can probably take 30-50 of them down to a single image download.

Final thing I noticed is that you have a lot of JavaScript loading right up near the top of the page. Try moving some of that (where possible) to later in the page and also look into asynchronously loading the js where you can.

I think that's a lot of suggestions for you to try. After you solve those issues, take a look at leveraging a CDN and other caching services to help speed things up for most visitors.

You can find a lot of these recommendations in a bit more detail in Steve Souder's book: High Performance Web Sites. The book is 5 years old and still as relevant today as ever.

Comment: In response to bybe, I just tried your site in websitetest.com as well as webpagetest.org. The results are pretty comparable. Both rank it in the top 50 percent of sites with page load times of about 5 seconds or so. Definitely not in the top but a very respectable time. I think you are misreading the Page Speed Score. When I ran it I got a result of 88/100 (fairly close to your 92/100). That does not mean that its faster than 88%  (or 92%) of sites. Instead thats just a number to compare against other tests using the same version of test. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I've just taken a look at websitetest.com and that website is completely not right at all, my site is amoung the 97% fastest and using that website is says its 26% from testing 13 locations. Their servers must be over loaded and I recommend you use a more reputatable testing site such as http://www.webpagetest.org which is backed by many big companies.

Looking at your contact details it looks like the focus audience is India? if that is correct you should use hosting where-ever your main audience is, or closest neighbor.